# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PrimarySmtpAddress'

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have a windows 10 environment running python 2.7, mentioned below is the code on which I am working on, which is expected to send scan the outlook application for a mail from 'xyz@domain.com' with subject 'send me a data doc' and if the same is found, it will send back a mail with required xlsx file. However while I execute this program it is giving the error as under:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\mail-test.py", line 13, in <module>
x = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PrimarySmtpAddress'
```

Mentioned below is the code:

```
import sys
import os
import win32com.client
import codecs
from win32com.client import constants
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("iso-8859-1")(sys.stdout, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
all_inbox = inbox.Items
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Class == 43:
        if msg.SenderEmailType == 'EX':
                x = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
                if x == 'xyz@domain.com':
                    message = msg.Subject
                    a = message.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
                    if (message == 'send me a data doc') and (msg.UnRead == True):
                        olMailItem = 0x0
                        obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
                        newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                        newMail.Subject = "data doc"
                        newMail.HTMLBody = "<body>Dear Sir,Madam,<br>Please find the requested details.<br><br><p></body>"
                        newMail.To = x
                        attachment1 = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\data.xlsx"
                        newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
                        newMail.Send()
                        msg.UnRead = False
```

Kindly assist in eliminating this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means that `msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser()` returned `None`. Are you certain there is an exchange user for that sender?

Comment: Yes Martijn, I am running this code with a outlook application logged in with AD user, and outlook emails are fully functioning while this code is running, not sure whether this answer's your question. can you confirm.

Comment: I have 0 experience with accessing Outlook over COM. All I know is that the exception is caused by `msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser()` returning `None`, probably indicating that for that given sender, there is no exchange user associated. Perhaps the email was sent by someone outside of the organisation?

Comment: I Second, @MartijnPieters second comment! You are checking if the address is gmail so obviously the email originated outside your organization so the user will not have an account on your AD

Comment: To avoid this confusion of domain, gmail id, have edited the sample gmail id with domain address, however the error remains same.

Comment: Have further troubleshooted, and found the issue at line all_inbox = inbox.Items, this line is resulting into <COMObject <unknown>> when i print all_inbox, however when i print variable inbox it is giving "Inbox" as output, so looks to be the issue that inbox.Items is actually unable to fetch the items from inbox, can somebody help here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the issue finally, the error was because one of the email in the inbox was group email address, which was resulting into such error, finally by simply moving/deleting that email the error is gone and program is functioning as expected. Though would welcome if somebody can share how to handle such group email address. And why such group email address causes an error as given above.
Thanks to all who have spent their time to assist me here.